# Hide dock panel space

Tags: c#, wpf, dockpanel

I want to create a window with two button, first one is fixed, the second one is in appearance and disappearance.
But when the second one is hidden the window continue to allow it's space.
I don't want it. How can I resolve? 
Thx

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DockPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Width="auto" />
    </DockPanel>

    <DockPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="button1_Click" />
    </DockPanel>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Difference between Hidden and Collapsed, is reserving space on your layout. Hidden reserves it, Collapsed isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Collapsed" instead of "Hidden".